# Android BottomAppBar Distribute Buttons horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-bottomappbar, bottomappbar

I want to use BottomAppBar without the Navigation drawer control and 
Floating Action Button. When The buttons are added they are justified to right or left.

[image]

- I want to distribute the action icons horizontally. I couldn't find a solution around and in the Android developer [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomappbar/BottomAppBar). How is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: BottomAppBar is same as Top Toolbar. If you want to distribute them horizontally use custom view or BottomNavigationView.

Comment: Could the downvoters write the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE**

if you want remove `Navigation drawer control` just remove **`app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer"`** from **`BottomAppBar`**

[output when your removed `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer"`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5tvu.png)

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">


    <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="end"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Graddle fails when `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` added.

Comment: Manifest Nerger failure.. org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures

Comment: @kelalaka share your `build.gradle` with question

Comment: Ok. Do I need material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar or BottomAppBar  is enugh?

Comment: @kelalaka use `com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar`

Comment: Asked please [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54554413/android-studio-manifest-merger-failed-with-multiple-errors-with-material1-0-0)

Comment: If you add that this needs AndroidX, will better answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the notification icon by removing the line:

```
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer"
```

From

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
    android:id="@+id/bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="58dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_drawer">
```

Then you can add left and right padding in bottomappbar:

```
<android.support.design.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
        android:theme="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomAppBar"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:paddingStart="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:paddingEnd="40dp"
        android:paddingRight="40dp"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:fabAlignmentMode="center"/>
```

That will center the four icons in the middle of the bottomAppBar.

Last step is to add padding/margins on the icons/imageviews and you should have yourself a nice even horizontally distributed four icons. I think the accepted answer doesn't quite achieve this.

Comment: Could you also add a screenshot to your answer?