# Android Studio : Manifest merger failed with multiple errors with material:1.0.0

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest

After adding `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` into built.gradle I've got an error

Android Studio : Manifest merger failed with multiple errors

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xyz.yzt"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    api 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    api 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    api 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    api 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'me.zhanghai.android.materialratingbar:library:1.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

}
```

Errors starts with:

```
org.gradle.execution.MultipleBuildFailures: Build completed with 1 failures.
```

Any ideas to resolve?

Comment: this might be because you don't use androidx dependencies for your support libraries

Comment: After migration, it seem all fine now. Lot to learn. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be because you don't use androidx dependencies for your support libraries.

Migrate to AndroidX